# XSLT/SVG - Choose Statement Screws up my Template

Tags: xml, xslt, svg

I'm trying to draw a pie chart and I'm starting with just 1 slice. I'm trying to use the path of SVG to do this so I'm having to calculate points to draw to based on data. My issue is that there is one number that is dependent on whether or not the angle of my value is greater than 3.14.

XML file:

```
<RESULTS>
 <ROW>
   <PASSED>2267</PASSED>
   <FAILED>30</FAILED>
   <CAUTION>11</CAUTION>
   <BLOCKED>10</BLOCKED>
   <NOTRUN>773</NOTRUN>
   <TOTAL>3091</TOTAL>
 </ROW>
</RESULTS>
```

XSLT with choose statement:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
     xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" 
     xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
     xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
     xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">

<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/RESULTS">
     <svg width="900" height="400">

     <xsl:for-each select="ROW">

    <xsl:variable name="currentAngle"
          select="((PASSED div TOTAL * 360.0) * .0174532925)"/>    

    <path style="fill:#ff0000;stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
          <xsl:attribute name="d">
               <xsl:text>M200, 200 L200, 20 A180, 180 0</xsl:text> 
               <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
               <xsl:choose>
                     <xsl:when test="$currentAngle &gt; 3.14"> 
                          <xsl:text>1 </xsl:text>
                     </xsl:when>
                     <xsl:otherwise>
                          <xsl:text>0 </xsl:text>
                     </xsl:otherwise>
                </xsl:choose>
                <xsl:text>,1 </xsl:text>
            <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="200 - ((1 - (($currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 2) + (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 24) - (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle  * $currentAngle) div 720) + (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 40320)) * 180)"/>
                <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="200 - (($currentAngle - (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 6) + (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 120) - (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 5040) + (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 362880)) * 180)"/>
           <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
           <xsl:text> Z</xsl:text>
           </xsl:attribute>
    </path>

     </xsl:for-each>
     </svg>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

If I replace the choose statement and just put in required number it will work. However, I will not always know which number I need to put in there so the choose statement is essential:

```
<path style="fill:#ff0000;stroke:black;stroke-width:1">
      <xsl:attribute name="d">
        <xsl:text>M200, 200 L200, 20 A180, 180 0 1,</xsl:text> 
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text>1 </xsl:text>
        <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
        <xsl:value-of select="200 - ((1 - (($currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 2) + (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 24) - (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle  * $currentAngle) div 720) + (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 40320)) * 180)"/>
            <xsl:text>, </xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="200 - (($currentAngle - (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 6) + (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 120) - (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 5040) + (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 362880)) * 180)"/>
             <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
             <xsl:text> Z</xsl:text>
           </xsl:attribute>
  </path>
```

The output of the one with the choose statement is just one line straight up and down and isn't finishing the arc to part of the path. The second one finished the pie slice. Why is it skipping through the choose statement and how do I fix it so I can generate my pie chart?

EDIT:

It is not skipping over the choose statement but it is not recognizing the spaces I'm putting in between. So for example my output might look like this:

```
<path d="M200, 200 L200, 20 A 180, 180 00, 1236, 23">
```

Instead of:

```
<path d="M200, 200 L200, 20 A 180, 180 0 0, 1 236, 23">
```

I've tried putting in a space using 4 spaces in between the text and trying to use the &# 160; where I had been trying to put spaces, but neither have worked. Any other suggestions?

Comment: Can you post the output SVG code (the value of the relevant attribute, don't need the whole thing).  It's hard to troubleshoot the XSLT without knowing exactly what it is currently doing.  It is likely that some of your whitespace is disappearing or you are otherwise ending up with invalid numbers in the arc command.  SVG error handling is to draw the path up to the first error and then ignore the rest, which is why you were only getting the straight line.

Comment: I compared your outputs and I suppose it is the misplaced comma. It should be placed in the `xsl:choose` texts rather than in the `xsl:text` after the `xsl:choose`.

Comment: Actually I realized the issue - it isn't recognizing the spacing.

Comment: @AmeliaBR thanks for leading me to notice the actual issue. I've edited my question to show the output. Any suggestions on how to get a space in there?

Comment: @Tomalak - I didn't know that. I was trying to using EXSLT math functions which wasn't compatible with my xslt processor so I went this route. Didn't even think of looking into XPath. Knowing that will make my life so much easier. Thank you!

Comment: @Tomalak There is no `pow()` function in XPath 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edits, it is clear that the problem is that the whitespace added via

```
    <xsl:text> </xsl:text>
```

is being collapsed.

You could try playing around with the [XSLT whitespace settings](http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt#strip).  However, an easier fix is simply to replace whitespace with commas, which are valid for separating all numbers in a path command, not just coordinate pairs.  You can also just add the commas at the end of existing text blocks to reduce the number of elements:

```
      <xsl:attribute name="d">
         <xsl:text>M200, 200 L200, 20 A180, 180 0,</xsl:text> 
         <xsl:choose>
                 <xsl:when test="$currentAngle &gt; 3.14"> 
                      <xsl:text>1,</xsl:text>
                 </xsl:when>
                 <xsl:otherwise>
                      <xsl:text>0,</xsl:text>
                 </xsl:otherwise>
         </xsl:choose>
         <xsl:text>1,</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="200 - ((1 - (($currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 2) + (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 24) - (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle  * $currentAngle) div 720) + (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 40320)) * 180)"/>
         <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
         <xsl:value-of select="200 - (($currentAngle - (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 6) + (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 120) - (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 5040) + (($currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle * $currentAngle) div 362880)) * 180)"/>
         <xsl:text>Z</xsl:text>
      </xsl:attribute>
```

I'll let you figure out a more compact notation for your trigonometric approximations (as recommended by @Tomalak in the comments)...

Comment: @Erin Note that the `<xsl:text>` is not strictly necessary. You could simply write `<xsl:otherwise>0,</xsl:otherwise>` (etc.) with the same effect.

Comment: @Amelia `<xsl:text>M200, 200 L200, 20 A180, 180 0 </xsl:text>` (note the whitespace at the end) would work as well.

Comment: @Tomalak  Thanks for clarifying.  I wasn't sure if non-empty text elements would be trimmed so I added the comma for good measure.